# Typescript interface property augumentation via custom.d.ts

Tags: reactjs, typescript

i need to augument TypographyProps { variant: 'primary', 'secondary' } and add to variants new variants via type augumentation.

Example:

I have monorepo

```
packages/
----- web-1
----- web-2
----- ui-library
---------- Typography/Typography.tsx


export interface DefaultVariant {
  variant: 'variant-1' | 'variant-3' | 'variant-2'
}

export interface VariantOverrides {}

type Merge<X, Y> = {
  [K in keyof X | keyof Y]:
    | (K extends keyof X ? X[K] : never)
    | (K extends keyof Y ? Y[K] : never)
}

export interface TypographyProps {
  variant: Merge<DefaultVariant, VariantOverrides>
}

export const Typography = ({ variant }: TypographyProps) => {
  return <div>{variant}</div>
}




// types in web-1 package
declare module 'ui-library' {
  import 'ui-library'

  export interface VariantOverrides {
    variant: 'variant-4' | 'variant-5'
  }
}

// types in web-2 package
declare module 'ui-library' {
  import 'ui-library'

  export interface VariantOverrides {
    variant: 'variant-55' | 'variant-46'
  }
}
```

Doest anyone know why this isnt work? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you wanting these new properties to be available to all the other modules just by virtue of the module existing in the same project, or do you only need to expand on the base type within the one your consuming?

Comment: My idea was to enhance props per project.

Comment: @AdamThomas My idea was to enhance props per project. Variants in web-1 and web-2 are different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This approach is possible just with enums because types cant be augumented.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Button from './packages/common/components/Button';


declare global {
  namespace Common {
    enum Variants {
      v2 = 'v2',
    }
  }
}

export default function App() {
  return <Button variants="v1" />;
}



/// 


import * as React from 'react';

declare global {
  namespace Common {
    enum Variants {
      v1 = 'v1',
    }

    interface ButtonProps {
      variants: keyof typeof Variants;
    }
  }
}

function Button({ variants }: Common.ButtonProps) {
  return <button>Test</button>;
}

export default Button;
```